# Ng2-charts in Angular 13 : Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I'm trying to add ng2-charts to angular application, but it gives me weird errors.

I installed ng2-charts version 3.0.9 with:
 `npm i ng2-charts@3.0.9`

`npm i chart.js`

Then added NgChartsModule to app.module.ts.

Here is my typescript file:

```
salesData: ChartData<'line'> = {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
    datasets: [
      { label: 'Mobiles', data: [1000, 1200, 1050, 2000, 500], tension: 0.5 },
      { label: 'Laptop', data: [200, 100, 400, 50, 90], tension: 0.5 },
      { label: 'AC', data: [500, 400, 350, 450, 650], tension: 0.5 },
      { label: 'Headset', data: [1200, 1500, 1020, 1600, 900], tension: 0.5 },
    ],
  };

  chartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Monthly Sales Data',
      },
    },
  };
```

Here is HTML:

```
<canvas
          baseChart
          [data]="salesData"
          [type]="'bar'"
          [options]="chartOptions"
        >
        </canvas>
```

For each property I get error:

```
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you so much.

Installing different versions of packages but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have a similar problem.

Comment: Where do you see this error? I get similar error messages when I execute my tests (`ng test`).
This is what I found on GitHub: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/1595